# hyperlink tag makes line break in domTab

Tags: html, hyperlink, line-breaks

I'm using tabs from: http://onlinetools.org/tools/domtabdata/

when ever I add a hyperlink, it breaks the line. I tried

```
white-space:nowrap;
<nobr></nobr>
```

and it still doesn't work.
Can any one help with this?

**you can find my codes here: http://jsfiddle.net/bnabaei/4Twkx/**

Comment: We will need more information to help you. Provide your code here (HTML/CSS) or a link to your page.

Comment: Thanks. I added link to my code.

Comment: everything seems fine in your fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
div.domtab div a:link,
div.domtab div a:visited,
div.domtab div a:active
{
    color:#094AB2;
    display:inline; /* Change it from display:block to display:inline */     
    font-size:1em;
    word-break:break-all;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Also please change this... SPACES ARE NOT FOR FORMATTING  :D and besides that there's no need to add `&nbsp;` to try center them manually...

So... remove them...

```
<div id="other" class="domtab doprevnext">
    <ul class="domtabs">
        <li><a href="#t1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#t2">Research</a></li>
        <li><a href="#t3">Publications</a></li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

And simply add this on your CSS:

```
div.domtab {
    padding:0 2em;
    width:80%;
    font-size:90%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;  /* Just add this line and let the CSS center them for you... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On line 122 in your css, you give your links `display: block;`. This causes them to take up the entire line they're on. Comment it out and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Skishore for your help!